# Are there octagonal box extenders that are slimmer than 1 1/2" deep?

Tags: electrical, ceiling

Is there an octagonal box extender that's slimmer than 1 1/2" deep? So far I haven't been able to find one.

Here's why: to cover up 30 years of patching on one of my plaster and lath ceilings, I'm considering covering the entire ceiling with 3/8" drywall, but that solution will leave two electrical boxes sunken into the new ceiling. I could re-mount the boxes deeper into the ceiling and use a 1 1/2" box extender, or I could replace my boxes with deeper ones, but it'd be easier if I could just affix a slim box extender and be done with the job.

Does anyone make a skinny box extender?

Comment: Check out the 'big walley' system of lathe and plaster repair...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a 1/2 inch [extender](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-4-in-Blue-Nonmetallic-Round-Plaster-Mud-Ring-for-Electrical-Ceiling-Box-A471RR/100149592) that fits octagonal boxes:

[image: box extender]

Comment: very cool. Do you know if it's OK per the NEC to put a non-metallic extender on top of a metal box?

Comment: Is this a metallic sheathed cable system (sometimes called BX) or is it non-metallic (sometimes called Romex)? If non-metallic, I don't think the composition of the boxes or extenders have any bearing. If it is metallic cable DO NOT USE ANYTHING BUT METAL. BX type systems rely on the box itself for ground and you need actual metal to metal contact. Not certain of exactly what code says and welcome weigh in from the community.

Comment: I don't believe the NEC still allows the metal armor to be used as ground in BX/AC; modern installations require a dedicated ground wire. Maybe someone with a NEC reference handy and confirm?

Comment: My concern is an old system that did use the armor as ground. Very common in older cities such as NYC. Still, good to check the code.

Comment: If the metal box is grounded (through whichever means), you can add a plastic extender as long as you ground the fixture to the box.  Most light fixtures nowadays have a ground terminal, so as long as you tie that into the circuits ground (which should be bonded to the metal box anyway) you should be fine.

Comment: Knew we could count on Tester101 for the rules!

Comment: It's NM cable. The fixture itself has no ground wire because it's one of those all-plastic luminaires that have no exposed metal parts.

Comment: It sounds like you are OK. If you can't find something like this locally, you probably can order from HD or Lowes online.

Comment: To clarify for those who stumble across this in the future: It's NEC-legal to use flexible metallic conduit as ground in some situations (basically a short run, like a three-foot whip between a can light and a junction box). It'd be necessary to consult local codes to get the actual length where it's ok, but it's not very far. Also, MC uses a real same-size ground wire, while BX (sometimes AKA "AC") uses the armor in conjunction with a small bonding strip attached to the jacket. Without the bonding strip, BX is just armored cable. i don't trust BX, and always pull a wire in FMC. ;)